# sails: how to redirect after creating a model with the built-in crud operations?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm dong some quick testing with the Sails framework for Node.

I like the way default CRUD-operations work out of the box, once a model and a controller (e.g.: for `user` ) are created.

I'm having a bit trouble with extending the basics though.

Say:

- I've created a User-model and empty User-controller.
- This should give me default Rest and Crud operations.
- I've defined a user-signup form that does as `POST` to `user/create`. This functionality is defined out of the box.

This works, but results in displaying the created JSON at `user/create`. 
How do I extend this to redirect to a certain url for example the user profile? (e.g.: `GET user`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need your own controller method. It could be as simple as below.

```
create: function(req, res) {
  User.create(req.body).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      //Handle Error
    }
    return res.redirect('/somewhere')
  });
}
```

Comment: what if I don't want to override default create method because if we override that then what is a meaning of having REST API out of a box?