# Sails.js redirect a route to another route

Tags: sails.js

So in routes there is a way to redirect a route to another route for example

`'/alias' : '/some/other/route'`

However, how do I redirect while also keeping certain aspects of the url for example `'/item/a_variable'` to `'item/bags/a_variable'`. So if someone types **/item/123** it should redirect to **/item/bags/123**. Or if **/item/215**, redirect it to **item/bags/215**

Comment: Maybe try this out: [sails-how-to-redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155570/sails-how-to-redirect-after-creating-a-model-with-the-built-in-crud-operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a method that would do that?

Something like :

```
redirect : function(req, res) {
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var new Path = path.split("/")[0] + "/bags/" + path.split("/")[1];
  res.redirect(newPath);
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using something like this at the moment. Just was wondering if there was a direct way from the routes itself.